# I don´t know how to push a tree into a Stack

Tags: java

Hi I am working with the Stack class in java, the problem that I have is that in this Stack I want to insert (to push) elements of type String, but i also want to insert a tree, the code is the following:

```
public static void Expression(Stack<String> exp)
    {
        boolean error = false;
        String leftExp,rightExp = "";
        Stack<String> stackOp = new Stack<String>();
        while(!exp.empty() && (error == false))
        {   
            switch(elementType(exp.peek())){
               case 'I':
                  error = true;
                  break;
               case 'O':
                  if(stackOp.size() < 2)
                     error = true;
                  else
                  {
                      rightExp = stackOp.pop();
                      leftExp = stackOp.pop();
                      Tree subTree = new Tree();
                      subTree.insertNode(exp.peek());
                      subTree.insertNode(rightExp);
                      subTree.insertNode(leftExp);
                      stackOp.push(subTree);//here is were I have the mistake
                  }
                  break;
               default:
                  stackOp.push(exp.peek());
            }
        }
    }

    public static char elementType(String car){
        char c = 'Z';
        if(car.equals("("))
           c = 'I';
        else if(car.equals(")"))
           c = 'D';
        else if(car.equals("+") || car.equals("-") || car.equals("*") || car.equals("/"))
           c = 'O';
        return c;
    }
```

This code basically transforms a math expression into a binary tree, for this I need an input, which is the expression, an output which is the binary tree, and another local stack that contains variables, numbers, and subtrees. But how can i make a Stack that contains elements of different types?

Comment: Stack is a legacy (obsolete) collection, it's recommended to use Deque (as interface) and ArrayDeque (as implementation) instead.

Comment: `Stack<String>` can contain only String literals. You need to modify your logic or remove the Type from it`Stack`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that can hold anything you want to put on the stack -- I think using a string to designate your operation is a bit clumsy, but suit yourself.  If you have a class that is `StackElement`, it can contain a type indicator (look into Java enums) and methods to do or obtain whatever you want.

You could define `StackElement` to contain a reference to one of several types, then also define all the methods of all the types it might contain; the ones that apply would be pass-throughs (if the type is an operation, a pass-through for getOperationType()), and the others would throw illegalOperationException, or something.  So if you try to call getOperationType() on a value, it throws an exception, same for calling getValue() on an operation, etc.

A nice thing about doing it this way is that you do not have to do any `instanceof` testing of the types you have stored.  You can declare your FILO queue to hold StackElement objects, create them with the types you want, and use them, all without `instanceof` or otherwise breaking OO style.

```
public class StackElement
{
  private StackElementType type;
  private StackOperation   operation;
  private StackValue       value;

  public StackElementType getType() { return type; }

  public StackOperation getOperation() 
  {
    switch (type)
    {
      case StackElementType.OPERATION: return operation;
      default: throw IllegalOperationException
                ("getOperation() on type " + type.toString());
    } 
  }

  public StackValue getValue()
  {
    switch (type)
    {
      case StackElementType.VALUE: return value;
      default: throw IllegalOperationException
                ("getValue on type " + type.toString());
    }
  }
}
```